# How to append consecutive elements of a js array to consecutive tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the content of three `<span>` elements using an array of three elements `["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]`.

The html after running the JQuery should look like:

```
<div class='main'>
  <span class='valueInput'>Saab</span>
  <span class='valueInput'>Volvo</span>
  <span class='valueInput'>BMW</span>
</div>
```

Here is what I have now:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $spots = $('.valueInput').text();
  var $cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
  $spots.text($cars);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main'>
  <span class='valueInput'></span>
  <span class='valueInput'></span>
  <span class='valueInput'></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code as follows, and search before you post another question.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $spots = $('.valueInput');
  var $cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
  $spots.each(function(i) {
    $(this).text($cars[i]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main'>
  <span class='valueInput'></span>
  <span class='valueInput'></span>
  <span class='valueInput'></span>
</div>
```